# Reinstalling Plesk via SSH

Tags: php, yum

I deleted PHP via SSH using yum as an update would not work, but it seems to have also removed Plesk - I presume because it is dependent upon PHP?

Is it possible to restore or reinstall Plesk via SSH?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `yum install plesk` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

If you new to Linux and Plesk, I would rather not recommend you installing Plesk by yum. Plesk autoinstaller does several extra configuration steps which yum will not perform, so even if installed, you won't be able to access Plesk until you do all these configurations.

I can suggest two options

1. Download [Plesk autoinstaller](http://www.parallels.com/download/plesk/10), run it in SSH and do installation through it. It has sufficiently simple interactive interface. Unfortunately it may not work if you already have the product half-installed by yum manually.
2. if #1 won't help, run so called [bootstrapper](http://kb.parallels.com/en/9276) which does a lot of essential configuration for Plesk. i.e. if you are on the latest Plesk it will be something like

   /usr/local/psa/bootstrapper/pp10.13.4-bootstrapper/bootstrapper.sh repair
   If you don't have this file, run whatever the latest one you have in `/usr/local/psa/bootstrapper/` folder

Hope something of that can repair your installation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I mean you can do *almost* anything via SSH. For your needs, just do

```
ssh <user>@<something> "yum install plesk -y"
```

Although I think it would ultimately be better to shell into the OS and do the Yum install.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help... I'm new to Linux I'm afraid!

Comment: This is what I get...  I presume I need to direct it to the Plesk repository?

Comment: [root@ntdd3027-g14ec ~]# yum install plesk -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * updates: mirror01.th.ifl.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package plesk available.
Nothing to do

Comment: Oh, looks like you have the the Atomicorp repo, but it might not be enabled. Append a `--enablerepo=atomic` to the yum install and that should fix it

Comment: That didn't work so I tried 'yum -y install psa psa-autoinstaller' and got this below - does that mean that Plesk is still installed? Yet if I navigate to where the login should be at https://62.128.155.119:8443/ I just get a 404 error? Is there anyway of checking through SSH that Plesk is installed and actually running? Thanks!

Comment: [root@ntdd3027-g14ec ~]# yum -y install psa psa-autoinstaller
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * updates: mirror01.th.ifl.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from Plesk Server Administrator
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package matching psa-autoinstaller-3.10.1-110812.13.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
Resolving Dependencies

Comment: There is then a long list of errors - mainly 'command not found' - too long to post on here!